# chrome extensension background.js events don't run

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to create a basic chrome extension that opens a new tab when user clicks on the extension. It seems like it doesn't work. When I open extension (click on it), nothing happens (the new tab or window doesn't open).

1.) I created a new project by command `yarn create vite chrome-sf-poc --template react`

2.) This is the script for generating bundle `yarn build && cp src/manifest.json dist/ && public/background.js dist/`

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "DEV Articles",
  "description": "A quick way to browse top posts from DEV Community.",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting", "tabs", "runtime"]
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({
    url: chrome.extension.getURL("https://www.google.com/"),
    selected: true,
  });

  chrome.tabs.create({
    url: chrome.extension.getURL("https://www.google.com/"),
    selected: true,
  });
});

chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function () {
  chrome.tabs.create({
    url: chrome.extension.getURL("https://www.google.com/"),
    selected: true,
  });

  chrome.tabs.create({
    url: chrome.extension.getURL("https://www.google.com/"),
    selected: true,
  });
});
```

When I load the extension into chrome, it says that service worker is inactive:

[image]

Comment: V2 and V3 are mixed. did you modify the output of the script?

Comment: Also you can't specify default_popup and use onClicked in the background script. Choose one.

Comment: Did you click on the red "Errors" button and look at the errors?

Comment: @NorioYamamoto what do you mean by v2 and v3 are mixed?

Comment: @wOxxOm does it mean it's not possible to open popup window and a new tab on click event?

Comment: @ThomasMueller yes, it says that `runtime` permission is wrong. I removed that.

Comment: @Matt, chrome.browserAction is V2.

Comment: It means if you choose default_popup you should put the code in its popup.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the script outputs V2.
You are trying to migrate it to V3 and failing.
I fixed it.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "DEV Articles",
  "description": "A quick way to browse top posts from DEV Community.",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "action": {
    "default_title": "hoge"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

background.js

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: "https://www.google.com/" });
});

chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function () {
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: "https://www.google.com/" });
});
```